# Randomly Generate Letters According to their Frequency of Use?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, pseudocode

How can I randomly generate letters according to their frequency of use in common speech?

Any pseudo-code appreciated, but an implementation in Java would be fantastic. Otherwise just a poke in the right direction would be helpful.

Note: I don't need to generate the frequencies of usage - I'm sure I can look that up easily enough.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073235/random-weighted-choice and many others (search "weighted random generation")

Comment: @Eli: sorry - didn't realise its name.

Comment: `fEnglish = new[] {8.167f,1.492f,2.782f,4.253f,12.702f,2.228f,2.015f,6.094f,
6.966f,0.153f,0.772f,4.025f,2.406f,6.749f,7.507f,1.929f,0.095f,5.987f,
6.327f,9.056f,2.758f,0.978f,2.361f,0.150f,1.974f,0.074f};`
and then...

Comment: `public static int RandomFromFrequencyArray(this float[] f)
    {
    float sum = 0f;
    foreach (float ff in f) sum += ff;

    int kF = f.Length;
    int result = 0;
    float sumSoFar = f[0];
    float percentageResult = Random.Range(0f, sum );

    while (sumSoFar < percentageResult)
        {
        ++result;
        sumSoFar += f[result];

        if ( result >= kF ) {Debug.Log("woe..."); return (kF-1);}
        }

    return result;
    }`

Comment: The frequency array does NOT HAVE TO ADD TO 100. So, it's totally fine to do this:

'(new[] {15f,5f,5f,1f}).RandomFromFrequencyArray();`
For example the vowels in English... just take the frequencies from the full alphabet frequencies (since it does not have to add to 100)...

'int trueRandomVowel = (new[] {8.167f,12.702f,6.966f,7.507f,2.758f}).RandomFromFrequencyArray();
return ("aeiou".ToCharArray())[v].ToString();'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am assuming that you store the frequencies as floating point numbers between 0 and 1 that total to make 1.

First you should prepare a table of cumulative frequencies, i.e. the sum of the frequency of that letter and all letters before it.

To simplify, if you start with this frequency distribution:

```
A  0.1
B  0.3
C  0.4
D  0.2
```

Your cumulative frequency table would be:

```
A  0.1
B  0.4 (= 0.1 + 0.3)
C  0.8 (= 0.1 + 0.3 + 0.4)
D  1.0 (= 0.1 + 0.3 + 0.4 + 0.2)
```

Now generate a random number between 0 and 1 and see where in this list that number lies. Choose the letter that has the smallest cumulative frequency larger than your random number. Some examples:

Say you randomly pick 0.612. This lies between 0.4 and 0.8, i.e. between B and C, so you'd choose C.

If your random number was 0.039, that comes before 0.1, i.e. before A, so choose A.

I hope that makes sense, otherwise feel free to ask for clarifications!

Answer (score 11):

One quick way to do it would be to generate a list of letters, where each letter appeared in the list in accordance with its frequency.  Say, if "e" was used 25.6% of the time, and your list had length 1000, it would have 256 "e"s.

Then you could just randomly pick spots from the list by using `(int) (Math.random() * 1000)` to generate random numbers between 0 and 999.

Comment: The best way to match the letter frequency of a particular text :-)

Comment: +1 It's a good suggestion, but not ideal if you have characters that occur with very small frequencies (e.g. 0.00001 or less). I guess it depends on what you need.

Comment: This has obvious precision limits, but might be preferable because it is so simple to implement and understand.

Comment: This is indeed the "video game approach" to randomness .. you make an list that has the things you want in the rough frequency you want them - and choose one.

Answer (score 6):

What I would do is scale the relative frequencies as floating point numbers such that their sum is 1.0. Then I would create an array of the *cumulative* totals per letter, i.e. the number that must be topped to get that letter and all those "below" it. Say the frequency of A is 10%, b is 2% and z is 1%; then your table would look something like this:

```
0.000 A ; from 0% to 10% gets you an A
0.100 B ; above 10% is at least a B
0.120 C ; 12% for C...
...
0.990 Z ; if your number is >= 99% then you get a Z
```

Then you generate yourself a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 and do a binary search in the array for the first number smaller than your random number. Then pick the letter at that position. Done.

Comment: Curse you, Mark Byers! Better explained answer, 3 minutes faster than me! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Not even a pseudo-code, but a possible approach is as follows:

Let p1, p2, ..., pk be the frequencies that you want to match.

1. Calculate the cumulative frequencies: p1, p1+p2, p1+p2+p3, ... , 1
2. Generate a random uniform (0,1) number x
3. Check which interval of the cumulative frequencies x belongs to: if it is between, say, p1+..+pi and p1+...+pi+p(i+1), then output the (i+1)st letter

Depending on how you implement the interval-finding, the procedure is usually more efficient if the p1,p2,... are sorted in decreasing order, because you will usually find the interval containing x sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Using a binary tree gives you a nice, clean way to find the right entry. Here, you start with a `frequency` map, where the keys are the symbols (English letters), and the values are the frequency of their occurrence. This gets inverted, and a `NavigableMap` is created where the keys are cumulative probability, and the values are symbols. That makes the lookup easy.

```
  private final Random generator = new Random();

  private final NavigableMap<Float, Integer> table = 
    new TreeMap<Float, Integer>();

  private final float max;

  public Frequency(Map<Integer, Float> frequency)
  {
    float total = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e : frequency.entrySet()) {
      total += e.getValue();
      table.put(total, e.getKey());
    }
    max = total;
  }

  /** 
   * Choose a random symbol. The choices are weighted by frequency.
   */ 
  public int roll()
  {
    Float key = generator.nextFloat() * max;
    return table.higherEntry(key).getValue();
  }
```