# How to generate random sequence of numbers in python?

Tags: python, random

How to generate random sequence of 1, 2, 3 provided that 80 % of numbers will 1, 15 % will 2 and 5 % will 3?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276787/python-selecting-numbers-with-associated-probabilities, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073235/random-weighted-choice, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `random` to get a random number in [0,1) and map your outputs to that interval.

```
from random import random

result = []

# Return 100 results (for instance)
for i in range(100):

    res = random()

    if res < 0.8:
        result.append(1)
    elif res < 0.95:
        result.append(2)
    else:
        result.append(3)

return result
```

This is a trivial solution. You may want to write a more elegant one that allows you to specify the probabilities for each number in a dedicated structure (list, dict,...) rather than in a if/else statement.

But then you might be better off using a dedicated library, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266645/4653485). Here's an example with scipy's [`stats.rv_discrete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html)

```
from scipy import stats
xk = np.arange(1, 4)
pk = (0.8, 0.15, 0.05)
custm = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(xk, pk))
# Return 100 results (for instance)
return custm.rvs(size=100)
```

Comment: I was going to post this answer only

Comment: Shouldn't there be a colon at the end of the `elif` line?

Comment: pk = (0.8, 0.15, 0.05) or your variant?

Comment: You're right. Fixed. The doc says "(xk, pk) where xk are integers with non-zero probabilities pk with sum(pk) = 1."

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
import random

sequence = []

desired_length = n # how many numbers you want
for i in range(desired_length):
    random_value = random.random()
    if random_value < .8:
        sequence.append(1)
    elif random_value < .95:
        sequence.append(2)
    else:
        sequence.append(3)

print sequence
```