# python generating random number with sub-ranges

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate n number of times a random integer from 1-100.  But first from 1 to 25, the probability of generating it is 1/8.  from 26 to 50 is a chance of 1/2.  the subrange 51 to 75 is 1/4, and the sub range from 76 to 100 has a 1/8 chance of generating.  I know how to generate a random int 1-100, but I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm with the sub-ranges.  Could someone guide me in the right direction?  I don't want to use any shortcuts like built in functions if there are for this.  I'm also coding in python.

```
import random

numOfTimes = int(raw_input())
counter = 0
while counter < numOfTimes:
    chance = random.randint(1,8)
    if chance == 1:
        randomNumber = random.randint(1,25)

    if chance == 2 or 3 or 4 or 5:
        randomNumber = random.randint(26,50)

    if chance == 6 or 7:
        randomNumber = random.randint(51,75)

    if chance == 8:
        randomNumber = random.randint(76,100)

    counter = counter + 1
    print randomNumber
```

Comment: While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a helpful answer if you show us what you've already tried. Here's some info on how to provide [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: And what is your criteria for "built in functions"? Can you not use random number functions? Is this a limitation placed by an instructor for a homework assignment?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073235/random-weighted-choice ?

Comment: `or` doesn't work like you think it does: please read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah) to understand why `chance == 6 or 7` won't work.

Comment: yeah I just spent time explaining it in my answer... I wasnt thinking ... there are probably a million places where it is explained (and probably better than I did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just draw from 8 numbers and then draw again from 25?

The first draw would determine which quarter of the hundred numbers you picked. Something like this:

```
n = random.randint(1, 8)
res = random.randint(1, 25)

if n == 1: pass
elif 2<=n<=5: res += 25
elif 6<=n<=7: res += 50
else: res +=75

return res
```

Comment: that is what i ended up doing.  I didn't quite understand it at first.  thank you

Comment: @user2958457 Joran's answer is much more scalable, since you can pick any number of numbers and their probabilities.

Comment: if i changed mine to elif statements would mine be correct?

Comment: his if statements are definately the problem with his code :P @user2958457 see my edited answer about what your problem actually is ... they are exclusive so `elif`s instead of `if`s wont do much

Answer (score 3):

**oops** fixed my typo `for i,v,r in en...` should have been `for i,(v,r) in enum...`

```
import random
key = random.random()
for i,(v,r) in enumerate(zip([.125,.625,.875],[(1,25),(26,50),(51,75)])):
    if key <= v:
        return random.randint(*r)
return random.randint(76,100)
```

something like that?

as to your problem

```
if chance == 2 or 3 or 4 or 5: #this wont work
    randomNumber = random.randint(26,50)

if chance == 6 or 7: #neither will this
    randomNumber = random.randint(51,75)
```

both of those are always true

`chance == 2` will be `True` or `False`, we will assume its False and put `False` in directly

`if 3` is the same as `if bool(3)` and is always `True` for **ANY** number that is not zero, so we will replace our `3` `4` and `5` with `True`

you can hopefully see the problem with `if False or True or True or True:`

you want something like

```
if chance == 2 or chance == 3 or chance == 4 or chance == 5:
```

which can be rewritten as

```
if chance in [2,3,4,5]:
```

or

```
if 2 <= chance <= 5:
```